# Run program as root without using sudo

Tags: command-line, sudo, scripts, administration

Can someone help me to run a ".run" on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.
My problem is I want to execute this program as super-user, but I don't want to use sudo to run it.
I just want to run with "./NvidiaTvOut.run", but the system says: "Operation not permitted".
It can appear easy, but I have searched a lot and I don't know what to do.

Best regards,

Comment: Can you post the output of `ls -l ./NvidiaTvOut.run`?

Comment: It's easier to answer if you explain why you don't want to use sudo. Is it because you don't want to enter the password, or some other reason?

Comment: if you needed root privileges to execute the file, you should have received an error "**root privileges are needed to execute**" blah blah blah **"are you root?"** or, "**permission denied"** in the subsequent output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible. However, the error "operation not permitted" is indicative of the **file itself** not having **executable** privileges.

It appears you are already in the directory with the file, if not cd into the directory first and then run the following before you try to run the file again.

```
sudo chmod +x NvidiaTvOut.run
```

You may now use

```
./NvidiaTvOut.run
```

to execute the file.

If you need root privileges, You will see "permission denied" instead of "operation not permitted".

The output of `ls -l` will show the file permissions for the files in the current directory and an x at the end of the permissions indicates the file is executable.

Please post any errors.

Answer (score 1):

I think that `NvidiaTvOut.run` file have not execution permission.

You can change it's permission as it's executable.

```
$ sudo chown $USER ./NvidiaTvOut.run

$ chmod +x ./NvidiaTvOut.run

$ ./NvidiaTvOut.run
```

or

```
$ sudo chmod 755 NvidiaTvOut.run

$ ./NvidiaTvOut.run
```

or

```
$ sudo chmod +x NvidiaTvOut.run

$ ./NvidiaTvOut.run
```

or If it is a shell script file, as following.

```
$ sh NvidiaTvOut.run
```

Comment: This won't run it as a super-user though.